# activator ui java.io file not found exception

Tags: sbt, typesafe-activator

Typing in activator ui from within the command line tool on windows 7 gives me the following error message.

```
C:\Program Files\activator-dist-1.3.6>activator ui
Found previous process id: 4164
Local repository: activator-launcher-local @ file:////C:/Program%20Files/activat
or-dist-1.3.6/repository
Play server process ID is 4068
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\activator-dist-1.3.6\RUNNING_PID
 (Access is denied)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
        at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$createServer$1.apply(NettyServe
r.scala:242)
        at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$createServer$1.apply(NettyServe
r.scala:230)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
        at play.core.server.NettyServer$.createServer(NettyServer.scala:230)
        at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$main$3.apply(NettyServer.scala:
289)
        at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$main$3.apply(NettyServer.scala:
284)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
        at play.core.server.NettyServer$.main(NettyServer.scala:284)
        at activator.UIMain$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(UIMain.scala:106)
        at activator.UIMain$$anonfun$run$1.apply(UIMain.scala:106)
        at activator.UIMain$$anonfun$run$1.apply(UIMain.scala:106)
        at activator.UIMain.withContextClassloader(UIMain.scala:217)
        at activator.UIMain.run(UIMain.scala:106)
        at activator.UIMain.run(UIMain.scala:86)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:128)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Error during sbt execution: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\acti
vator-dist-1.3.6\RUNNING_PID (Access is denied)
```

Having googled around I've seen similar issues with a similar exception, I haven't found a post dealing with the issue that IM experiencing though.

EDIT: I have found that if I install the minimal activator build and run the following command: `activator -Dhttp.port=9999 ui`. The activator launches in a browser, but I get the error posted above when trying to run the full install build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm 99% sure that your problem is because of a space in the path. Try putting the activator-dist somewhere there are no spaces.

It's mentioned here: 
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/3.0.x/Installing

> On Windows, add ;C:\path\to\activator to your PATH environment variable. Do not use a path with spaces.

Comment: This actually did work. Make sure that not one else is subscribed to the default port that typesafe activator uses or else it wont be able to launch.

Answer (score 1):

The activator is not able to create the file `RUNNING_PID`.  Run the command as an administrator user by using the `activator ui` command.